# Filtering out firebase events by nested parameters in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

What I'm trying to achieve is to filter out all Firebase events that have `event_params.key = 'firebase_event_origin'` and `event_params.value.string_value = 'auto'`

I'm expecting to get rows of events where specified events are excluded.

[image]

Things I've tried:

1. Filtering it directly in `WHERE` clause:

```
select * from **.events_intraday_* as a
where a.event_params <> ('firebase_event_origin',('auto'))
```

Which caused me getting this exception:

> No matching signature for operator = for argument types: ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, ...>>>, STRUCT<STRING, STRING>. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [10:5]

2. Filtering it with `EXISTS` function

```
select * from **.events_intraday_* as a
where exists 
    (
    select 1 from a
    where a.event_params.key = 'firebase_event_origin'
    and a.event_params.value.string_value <> 'auto'
    )
```

Which caused me getting this exception:

> Table "a" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table).

Answer (score 1):

I've been using EXISTS function in a wrong way - here's a correct code snippet that worked for me

```
where exists (
  select * from unnest(a.event_params)
  where key = 'firebase_event_origin'
  and value.string_value <> 'auto'
)
```